# Why does CppCheck give an array access out of bounds error for this static const array?

Tags: c++, namespaces, indexoutofboundsexception, static-analysis, cppcheck

CppCheck 1.67 has identified and array accessed out of bounds error on one of my projects. I didn't think the code was wrong, so I have stripped down the code to the bare minimum example that still raises the same error. Why does CppCheck give the following error for the first C++ example (inside a namespace) but not for the second example (without a namespace)?

Am I doing something wrong with the namespace on my array initialisation or is this an error in CppCheck?

**Reported error: "Array 'testArray[5]' accessed at index 5, which is out of bounds."**

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    class TestClass
    {
        static const int testArray[5];
    };

    const int TestClass::testArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

**No reported errors:**

```
class TestClass
{
    static const int testArray[5];
};

const int TestClass::testArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be an error in CppCheck, maybe is connected with this issue on the tracker:

[FP arrayIndexOutOfBounds: member variable of class declared in namespace](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/6146).

Comment: This answers my question, thanks. Will not worry about it any further. I think the bug is closed without a fix though?

Comment: Indeed. I've re-opened the ticket and provided a link to this question, hopefully they'll fix this.